# If the linear system Ax=b is consistent, does it follow that A and [A b] have the same rank? What about the other way around?

Tags: linear-algebra

"If the linear system Ax=b is consistent, does it follow that A and [A b] have the same rank?  What about the other way around?"

The forward direction is almost true by definition since if a system is consistent, it has a solution so b is just a linear combination and adding it doesn't add a new dimension.

For the backward direction, I think if taking away b keeps the rank the same, then it also implies b is a linear combination of A so I think the answer is also true.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Yes, this is basically (part of) the so-called Rouche-Capelli theorem. For the backward direction, your reasoning is correct. We can also equivalently reason by the contrapositive: if $b$ is not a solution, then by definition this means it is not in the span of the columns of $A$, and so it is linearly independent from them; so, adding $b$ to the list of column vectors to make an augmented matrix will increase the column rank.